# What is the purpose of diode between emitter and base in this capacitance multiplier?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, diodes

The picture below is an excerpt of Figure 2 of a DC/DC boost converter (see PDF [here](https://www.analog.com/media/en/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-176.pdf)). It is part of a capacitance multiplier. What is the purpose of this (anti-parallel) diode between emitter and base of the transistor? I couldn't find this in any literature for capacitance multiplying.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The diode protects the BJT (inverted BE voltage) assuming the input voltage disappears.
Output capacitors can then discharge through the diode ... and the 500 Ohm safely.

For completeness, I simulated another configuration like this one (big output capacitor).
Check the currents without or with an added diode (currents through BJT).
[image]

[image]

Comment: Great insight and demonstrations about spiking backwards the Base-collector current. I haven’t thought about that and your answer also clarified that.

Comment: It is a real pleasure. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Probably to protect the transistor. Most BJTs will only tolerate -5 or so volts VBE.